# Trying to make AJAX work on simple login form

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I have been trying for hours to make this work but I am not getting anything back when doing the ajax call. I am new to Ajax and it could probably be something you will see but that I am unable to. I would appreciate you help. Here is my code.

HTML

```
 <script>
$("#submitlogin").click(function() {

      inputs = {
        "logInUsername" : $('input[name=logInUsername]').val(),
        "logInPassword" : $('input[name=logInPassword]').val()
      };
      // since this is a username and password combo you will probably want to use $.post
      $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",           
        url: "loggnow.php",
        data: inputs,
        success: function() {
          $("#login").html("You are now logged in!");
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

loggnow.php

```
<?php
extract($_POST);

if($_POST)
{
   echo 'Yes the ajax posted';
}
?>
```

Comment: do you get a Javascript error or PHP error when trying to manually access that page?
also make sure you are giving the right path to the PHP file, what you have implies that both files are in the same directory

Comment: Yes i am able to access the page through the url address, and yes they are in the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitlogin").click(function() {
    inputs = {
        "logInUsername" : $('input[name=logInUsername]').val(),
        "logInPassword" : $('input[name=logInPassword]').val()
    };
    // since this is a username and password combo you will probably want to use $.post
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",           
        url: "loggnow.php",
        data: inputs,
        success: function() {
            $("#login").html("You are now logged in!");
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("error " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

This will give you an alert if an error occurs in AJAX with details

**EDIT:**

As Leo pointed it out, your code might be executing too fast, try the modified code above so that you make sure it runs after all the page has loaded

Comment: Thank you Dani, I tried this, and nothing came back.. the page does not change either but when i click the button it seems like it loads something for a second.. but then stays on the same page like nothing happened.

Comment: i updated my answer after Leo's suggestion
try it and let me know,  altho Leo's approach is also good i encourage you to use `$(document).ready` instead because it's more clear to read then just `$()` especially if you are dealing with huge code

Comment: Wow yeah this worked.. One last question what if i want to display the message "You are logged in from my .php page, can i do this?.. or how can i manipulate the sucess: function so that it gets some kind of response from the php

Comment: this should work: `success: function(data_returned_from_server) {$("#login").html(data_returned_from_server);}`

Comment: yup that should do
i suggest you have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for other useful stuff ;)

Comment: [look here too](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) - is the documentation for the $.post method (a shorthand for the $.ajax type=post you are using), it will make your code simpler :)

Comment: Oh man, i implemented that success: line and went back to not responding anything.. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.. I just want to do the <p>youa are logged in from the php </p> thank you for the info though :)

Comment: what should go under 'data_returned_from_server' because i literally added that lol

Comment: `data_returned_from_server` is just a string that contains the reply of php, in other words, anything you echo will be contained in the string for example

Answer (score 2):

Try to put your function inside

```
$(function(){
    //attach the button click here
});
```

this way your code will only run after the body loaded (so you are sure that you button exists) - look [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

you just need a web server host looks like this:http://127.0.0.1:8084/xxx

Comment: Where did you get the port number from?